# Hilbert space $\ell^2$ with standard basis

Tags: real-analysis

I have no idea to construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\ell^2$  such that $x_n = n^{-1/3}$ for infinitely many $n$.
Could you illustrate this for me?

Comment: Hi, I type the maths better for you. Here's how you can do it yourself in the future: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference People are more likely to answer a well-written and nicely typed question

Answer (score 2):

For example, you could have $x_n = n^{-1/3}$ when $n$ is a power of $2$, i.e.
$x_{2^k} = 2^{-k/3}$, and $x_n = 0$ otherwise.  Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-2k/3}$ converges, so this is in $l^2$.